# Scraping multiple pages property data with Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Need to scrap multiple pages data from the following website

https://dubai.dubizzle.com/en/property-for-rent/commercial/office/?page=1

The fields to get are "Price, description, area and location" for multiple pages. I have written only the following code. In addition I don't know how to parse the phone number, because it only appears when you have opened the particular link

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = "Dubizzle.csv"
f = open(file, "w")
Headers = "Price,Area,Description,Location,Website\n"
f.write(Headers)
for page in range(1, 4):
    url = "https://dubai.dubizzle.com/en/property-for-rent/commercial/office/?page={}".format(page)
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question in stackoverflow

Comment: Have a look at `requests` and `beautifulsoup` packages to give something a go.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the phone number you have to click on "Show phone number" button, that's right. But after inspecting the elements of the page you can see that phone number is already there, it's just hidden and will appear on the page after you click the button.

```
<img class="phone-num-img" src="data:image/png;base64,...
```

Unfortunately, the phone number is kept as a PNG image, so even though it's there, you will have to somehow parse the image to get the phone number itself.

Comment: Can you help in writing the script to parse the remaining data: "Price,Area,Description,Location" across multiple pages

Comment: Tell me what exactly is causing the problem. Are you familiar with BeautifulSoup? With that it should be pretty easy to parse Price, Area and Description. Regarding Location, gps coordinates also exist in HTML under script tags (in GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE and GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE keys of window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS object).